# SSH sessions doesn't terminate correctly

Tags: ssh, session

I'm having issues with some ssh sessions that doesn't seem to terminate properly. To make things even worse, the customer whos sessions is getting "stuck", well, they seem to have some kind of implemented solution and doesn't have the knowledge to fix the issue without the help of the developer. To top things off: This doesn't happen for all sessions from this user, maybe 1 out of 25-50.

Going through the logs, these lines are the ones when starting the SSH session. After this there is... Nothing.

```
sshd[5985]: Connection from 123.123.123.123 port 59739
sshd[5985]: Accepted password for USER from 123.123.123.123 port 59739 ssh2
sshd[5985]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user USER by (uid=0)
sshd[5985]: User child is on pid 5992
```

Usually there would be a line like this. But not when the sessions gets "stuck".

`sshd[51665]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user USER`

This what can be found by doing a simple ps -ef

```
USER 5992 5985 0 00:00 ? 00:00:02 sshd: USER@notty
```

All other users sessions are getting timed out after 10 mins with the following in sshd_config

```
ClientAliveInterval 600
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

And now i'm all out of ideas, so all inputs are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You have set the client but did you set the server timeout
edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
ServerAliveInterval 600
```

Comment: sshd_config is the server configuration and ssh_config is the client configuration as far as i know.

Comment: @eae try putiing serveraliveinterval in the ssh_config and test it.